# Pycharm Unexpected Result Output

Tags: python, web-applications, flask, pycharm

I'm a beginner at Pycharm. I'm using Flask web framework to develop a basic web application. I have written a simple code to display "Hello" on my browser, which it did. Strangely, when I add something to 'Hello', such as 'Hello my name is Yusef' and re-run the program; it won't show any changes, it still appears with message 'Hello' on my browser. Any idea, what I'm missing?

Below is my code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Perhaps you have to restart your web server.  It might have the old message cached.

Comment: I thought so, but as I'm a noob, how do I do that for pycharm? any advices will definitely be appreciated

Comment: @JohnGordon I just stopped the server and restarted it on my windows computer didn't really help. Is there anyway, i could clean off my cache?

Comment: I would recommend adding `debug` in `app.run(debug=True)`. This makes the running flask application to auto reload when code changes.

Comment: @lepsch it still outputs the same result, just 'Hello' and nothing else

Comment: As @John Gordon commented already, I'm pretty sure the app is running in background. I think you could have clicked "Disconnect" instead of "Terminate" process when PyCharm asked you to. This way the process continues to run in background. I would suggest you to reboot the system.

Comment: @Iepsch thanks mate, it worked. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the browser cache, this isn't a Pycharm issue, just clear your browser cache and you should be fine.
Open in incognito mode to avoid such issues.

Comment: Didn't really work apparently... I tried running on Incognito mode, same result

Comment: I tried running on a different browser, Mozilla Firefox, it still shows the similar error.